# Why does (name <keyword>) return nil?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, keyword

I'm scratching my head on this for a while. I have this hiccup snippet:

```
[:div.tab-pane {:id (name (:name t))} ...]
```

't' is a record with, among other fields, `:name` set to a keyword. This particular record has :name mapped to `:testgroup`.

If I run it like this:

```
[:div.tab-pane {:id (:name t)} ...]
```

The resulting html is not surprisingly: `<div id=":testgroup" class="tab-pane" .../>`

But when I run it calling `(name (:name t))` i get: `<div class="tab-pane" .../>`

This has nothing to do with hiccup, in my tests for this function I get a nil value in the {:id } map in the original [:div ...] vector , but why?

Answer (score 2):

Silly mistake. In case others run into it:

What I omitted above is that the function is part of a **protocol** extended on that particular record. That means that the symbol `name` inside the protocol method is shadowed by the `name` field of the record. Calling `clojure.core/name` instead of `name` solved the problem.